# Program behaves differently on two user accounts on same computer - NSLog also isn't working

Tags: xcode, cocoa, console, nslog

So this is a first for me... maybe someone else has had a similar issue and can suggest a solution:

Developing a program that does interaction through iCal using scripting bridge.  Developing it on my main account on my Macbook Pro.  Everything works perfectly.

After compiling, I copied the app to a second user account on the same Macbook Pro which is also configured as an administrative account, but now it behaves differently...

In this case, I generally add a bunch of NSLog statements with info such as variable contents, etc, to help me identify where the breakdown is occurring.

On my PRIMARY user account, the log correctly displays all of the information.  However, on the SECONDARY account, *some* of the NSLog statements display, while others do not display anything at all.

What is interesting is that the program is clearly executing code which comes *after* the NSLog statement in the same method.  It's as if it is simply skipping some of the NSLog statements when executing on the Secondary user account.

Just to be clear, some of the statements which is skipping are as simple as:

```
NSLog(@"Still working here.");
```

Baffled by this, and needless to say, making it quite difficult to debug the main functionality problem I'm having in my program with iCal and scripting bridge.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems most likely a problem with the code. I imagine you'll need to post more code to get any useful advice. Have you tried running the program in the debugger under the second user account?

Comment: Not yet.  I will try that today.  I can't imagine what the problem could be.  No compile or runtime errors on the main account.  We'll see what happens on the alt account when I try to compile and run from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

It turns out that it wasn't actually a problem with the code at all.  It was a problem with the operator...

Having recently upgraded from Xcode 3.6 to Xcode 4.3, I didn't realize that the default build file location had moved... so, I was simply copying an older version of the build file which was compiled before the NSLog tags in question were added.

Doh!

"Eliminate the impossible and whatever remains, however improbably, must be the truth."